# Code appears to jump lines in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a section of code that is appearing to 'jump'

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    SU_DefaultLoc.Text = My.Settings.DefaultLocation
    If My.Settings.DefaultLocation = "" Or File.Exists(My.Settings.DefaultLocation) = False Then
        MsgBox("start")
        My.Settings.DefaultLocation = FileBrowse(My.Settings.DefaultLocation)
        MsgBox(My.Settings.DefaultLocation)
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
    If My.Settings.SaveLocation = "" Then
        My.Settings.SaveLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If
    SU_DefaultLoc.Text = My.Settings.DefaultLocation
    Me.Text = "Delivery Scheduling - Version " & Me.ProductVersion
    My.Settings.UpdateLoad = False
    My.Settings.Save()
    LoadDatasets()
End Sub
```

The code runs correctly to display `msgbox("start")`

It then offers the browse dialog (on the next line of code) but then appears to execute the line `LoadDatasets()` (just above `End Sub`)

This subroutine (`LoadDatasets()`) has a try, catch statement with a messagebox on the catch, this message box is appearing next.

After you click OK (on the msgbox in LoadDatasets()) you get the `MsgBox(My.Settings.DefaultLocation)` on line 10 appear.

The `FileBrowse()` code is as follows:

```
    Function FileBrowse(Optional Location As String = "", _
                Optional Title As String = "Browse to the folder that stores the import files and click 'Open'") As String
    If Location = "" Then Location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    'Show Browse Info
    With FBD
        .InitialDirectory = Replace(Location, Split(Location, "\").ElementAt(UBound(Split(Location, "\"))), "")
        .Title = Title
    End With
    If FBD.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'clear old settings
        My.Settings.VanLoadDetails.Clear()
        My.Settings.OrderData.Clear()
        My.Settings.UpdateLoad = False
        FileBrowse = FBD.FileName
        LoadDatasets()
    Else
        'Do Nothing
        FileBrowse = ""
         End If

End Function
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does `appears to jump` mean? Are you debugging it? Does it just not run the code?

Comment: what i should have said was it appeared to execute the line LoadDatasets() - i have corrected the q. I am debugging it.

Comment: I think the FileBrowse() method is executed in another thread.

Comment: @Nadeem_MK i have added the filebrowse code, is openfiledialog (FBD) not displayed modally with `FBD.showdialog()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the code "*appears to execute `LoadDatasets()`*" because `FileBrowse` actually calls `LoadDatasets()`?

```
Function FileBrowse(Optional Location As String = "", _
                Optional Title As String = "Browse to the folder that stores the import files and click 'Open'") As String
    If Location = "" Then Location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    'Show Browse Info
    With FBD
        .InitialDirectory = Replace(Location, Split(Location, "\").ElementAt(UBound(Split(Location, "\"))), "")
        .Title = Title
    End With
    If FBD.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ...
        LoadDatasets() ' <--- here'
    Else
        ...

End Function
```

Comment: sometimes i surprise myself at how stupid i can be! Thanks very much.